# How to get Docker desktop on Ubuntu?

Tags: linux, docker, desktop

I am new to Docker/Kubernetes and trying to see if there is a way to get 'Docker Desktop' like functionality on Ubuntu, which is my primary development machine. All I know from my search is that the 'Docker Desktop' is only from Windows and Mac.

It contains many useful tools bundled together as below which is great for someone like me who is new to the ecosystem :

> Docker Desktop includes Docker Engine, Docker CLI client, Docker
> Compose, Notary, Kubernetes, and Credential Helper.

Is there a way to get docker desktop for Linux or is there anything similar?

Comment: `apt-get install docker-compose` gets you "Docker Engine", Docker CLI and Docker Compose.

Comment: Unless I am mistaken, `docker.io` is the main package on Ubuntu:  https://packages.ubuntu.com/source/focal/docker.io

Comment: "Is there a way to get docker desktop for Linux" -- no there is not.  "Docker Desktop" is a Windows/Mac thing as more in needed on those platforms.  They essentially shield an entire virtual machine installation.  None of that is needed on Linux.

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel That may have been the case in 2020, but I think this has chaged now: https://docs.docker.com/desktop/install/ubuntu/

Comment: Things to indeed change over time, such is the path of mankind.  I glanced at the desktop offering, and (very personally speaking) decided it's insane that it insist on shimming a VM between the kernel and itself .... to "compatible with the experience on other OSs". Thanks but not thanks.  But good to have choice, I am sure some people may enjoy having it.

Comment: As mentioned by @AndrewS in the comment, Docker Desktop for Linux has been released and no longer a `tech preview`. Link to the announcement: https://www.docker.com/blog/the-magic-of-docker-desktop-is-now-available-on-linux/

Comment: @DhavalD Good point. I have updated [my 2022 February answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70967611/6309) below.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Currently, docker desktop supported Mac, Windows only.

For ubuntu, you can use [Docker Engine](https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/ubuntu/) with [Portainer](https://www.portainer.io/installation/) (Web-based).

Other options:

- [LazyDocker](https://github.com/jesseduffield/lazydocker)

2022 Update:
[Docker Desktop for Linux (Tech Preview)](https://docs.docker.com/desktop/linux/)

Get more info about it at this [issuse](https://github.com/docker/roadmap/issues/39)
It is currently only available as a .deb for Ubuntu 21.04, 21.10 and Debian distributions.

Comment: It's also part of Ubuntu itself:  https://packages.ubuntu.com/source/focal/docker.io  So just do `sudo apt install docker.io`.

Comment: Thank you for your responses. I was looking for a complete package which has docker and Kubernetes and all other essentials like 'Docker desktop' has, but I think that kind of an option doesn't exist for Linux. I ended up installing each ( Docker and Kubernetes ) separately using `sudo wget -qO- https://get.docker.com | sh` for Docker and [Minikube](https://minikube.sigs.k8s.io/docs/start/) for Kubernetes.

Comment: `DockStation` and `Kitematic` are deprecated.

Answer (score 14):

Docker announced in a [blog post](https://www.docker.com/blog/accelerating-new-features-in-docker-desktop/) (16-Sep-2021):

> Docker Desktop for Linux will be available to all developers through
> the free Docker Personal and paid Docker Pro, Team, and Business
> subscriptions. If you’re interested in early access please sign-up for
> our developer preview program.

That's good news! While the Desktop features are not really "required" on Linux, I've grown to like the user interface and not needing to behave differently on the Linux platform is very welcome!

Answer (score 6):

[Feb. 2022](https://twitter.com/glours/status/1488799419357089792): there is now an official documentation (for what is still a Tech Preview)

Oct. 2022: [Docker Desktop 4.12](https://docs.docker.com/desktop/release-notes/#docker-desktop-4120) has been released, and the Linux distribution is no longer a tech preview.

> ### [Docker Desktop for Linux](https://docs.docker.com/desktop/linux/)

> ```bash
> curl https://desktop-stage.docker.com/linux/main/amd64/74134/docker-desktop.deb --output docker-desktop.deb
> sudo apt install ./docker-desktop.deb
>
> systemctl --user start docker-desktop
> systemctl --user enable docker-desktop
>
> journalctl --user --unit=docker-desktop
> ```

Answer (score 0):

In fact, there is a Docker Desktop for Linux, but not for all distros. Please visit the [official documentation](https://docs.docker.com/desktop/linux/) for more detailed explanation and for further changes. Since it is an experimental version, you should read the known issues before installing.

If you are interested, you can also visit their [public roadmap](https://github.com/docker/roadmap/projects/1)

The short tale is this:

> Docker Desktop for Linux (Tech Preview)
> (...) This Tech Preview is
> aimed at early adopters who would like to try an experimental build of Docker Desktop for Linux and provide feedback.(...) Download and install
> Docker Desktop for Linux is currently available on Ubuntu 21.04, 21.10 and Debian distributions.

This version runs a **Virtual Machine**.

*I strongly recommend to read the provided article*

Comment: Yes, see my [February answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70967611/6309) for installation.